# Return a value from a postgres insert and use it to insert a new record on a different table

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Please forgive me on this question. I am brand new to Postgres and I feel like a fool asking what to me seems like a simple question. I have an insert i need to do into two postgres 12 tables. The first one returns the PK that will be inserted into the second table as a foreign key. The problem is I get an error on the SQL. It doesn't like my declare statement. I know I must be doing something foolish. SQL is my weakest skill Any help would be greatly appreciated and this is my first attempt at using postgres.

**Now I get c# ERROR**: 23502: null value in column "paid" violates not-null constraint

*EDIT FOR CLARITY* : I need to get the second insert PK as a return value.

**Updated code**: Per Posted Answer

**I Updated GMB's response to be the answer** My Error of the constraint was because I didn't know I needed to update the the sequence to the current max ID of my imported data @GMB thanks so much for your reply!!!

```
-- FUNCTION: public."insert_totalRecord"(text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,bigint, out integer)
-- DROP FUNCTION public."insert_totalRecord"(text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,bigint, out integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."insert_totalRecord"(
    in cc text, 
    in mu text, 
    in re text, 
    in pc text, 
    in ad text, 
    in ad2 text,
    in pr text, 
    in gn text, 
    in mn text, 
    in fn text, 
    in af text, 
    in st text, 
    in iea text, 
    in pp text, 
    in drid bigint,
    out pid integer)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$
WITH t AS (
    INSERT INTO postaladdress (
        CountryCode,
        Municipality,
        Region,
        PostalCode, 
        Address1, 
        Address2) 
    VALUES (cc, mu, re, pc, ad, ad2) 
    RETURNING paid
)
INSERT INTO personaldata (
    Prefix,
    GivenName, 
    MiddleName, 
    FamilyName, 
    Affix,
    DStatus, 
    PostalAddressId, 
    InternetEmailAddress, 
    PrimaryPhone, 
    DId
)
SELECT 
    pr, 
    gn, 
    mn, 
    fn, 
    af, 
    st, 
    paid, 
    iea, 
    pp, 
    drid
FROM t
RETURNING pid;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public."FF_insert_totalRecord"(text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,bigint, OUT integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Your syntax error is because you're missing the `BEGIN` statement before the first `INSERT`. You'll need an `END` statement prior to the ending `$BODY$` also. I would suggest using a `record` variable type for `new_pa` and use `RETURNING * INTO new_pa`. Then reference `new_pa.id` in the next `INSERT`.

Comment: thanks for your speedy reply but I still got this error Even with the begin. Any other ideas?
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DECLARE"
LINE 30: DECLARE new_paid integer;

BEGIN 
DECLARE new_paid integer;
.....
END
$BODY$;

Comment: I'm not sure if you've moved the `BEGIN` statement yet but it comes after the declare block but before the first `INSERT`. Take a look at some of the examples here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createfunction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single query in Postgres:

```
WITH t AS (
    INSERT INTO postaladdress (
        CountryCode,
        Municipality,
        Region,
        PostalCode, 
        Address1, 
        Address2) 
    VALUES (cc, mu, re, pc, ad, ad2) 
    RETURNING my_new_paid
)
INSERT INTO personaldata (
    Prefix,
    GivenName, 
    MiddleName, 
    FamilyName, 
    Affix,
    DStatus, 
    PostalAddressId, 
    InternetEmailAddress, 
    PrimaryPhone, 
    DId
)
SELECT 
    pr, 
    gn, 
    mn, 
    fn, 
    af, 
    st, 
    my_new_paid, 
    iea, 
    pp, 
    drid
FROM t
RETURNING pid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. But I got this error:

ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return integer
DETAIL:  Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.

Comment: @theZelot: the query was missing a final `RETURNING`, I just added it.

Comment: That final version of code was accepted by postgres but when I Execute my C# code I get this error... I think maybe it's not getting the new id after inserting into postal address? Is there any way to verify?

23502: null value in column "paid" violates not-null constraint
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Npgsql.PostgresException: 23502: null value in column "paid" violates not-null constraint

Comment: The error coming back was my fault. I marked the answer above as useful. And the answer. thanks for the help!!! You're the best.